# OpenGL draw path traveled

Tags: c++, opengl

Today, I do:

- I'm storing coordernates(x,z) in a std::vector.
- I move and rotate the same background grid with:
  glRotatef(angle_value, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  glTranslatef(posX, posY, zoom_value);
- I draw line like this:
  glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
- The coordenates stored in std::vector I do an iterator:
  glVertex3f(iterator->x, iterator->y, 1);

Result:
[image]

My wished:
[image]

Comment: what is wrong? is it not have enough width?

Comment: Exact, not have width.

Comment: have you tried `glLineWidth`?

Comment: Yeah! I used it, but the curve and the width did not stay as I desire, just like in the figure.

Comment: Use a shader to define width of the line Yourself.

Answer (score 0):

render quads instead if lines composed from 2 consequent points and distortion of half width of your path to both perpendicular directions. in 2D is that easy just swap coordinates and negate on `(dx,dz)  -> (-dz,dx) , (dz,-dx)` scaled to size of `width/2`

So if you got 2 consequent 2D points `p(i),p(i-1)`  both with `(x,z)` coordinates then:

```cpp
du=p(i)-p(i-1)
dv=(du.z,-du.x)
dv*=width/(2.0*|dv|)

p0 = p(i)-dv
p1 = p(i)+dv
p2 = p(i-1)+dv
p3 = p(i-1)-dv
```

[image: img]

This will create gaps between consequent `QUADS` however to remedy that use only `p0,p1` and `QUAD_STRIP` ...

hope you know how to compute length of vector (`|dv|`) if not see:

- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

near bottom ...

Comment: I'll try!
In the place of (x, z) would not be (x, y)?

Comment: @CleitonBueno I tought you are using `x,z` as you got the first coordinates mentioned as such. It does not matter if you got `x,z` or `x,y` just use them the same across whole program.